# Using SQL Bulk Copy to fill a database table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel, sqlbulkcopy

I'm working on an web app using ASP.NET MVC4. I have an Excel file with several columns (some of them are useless) and I'd like to export the data to a related table by uploading the file.

One of my superiors told me to use SQL Bulk Copy to do that. I search some information about that but nothing really interesting (for example, nothing about how to map the excel columns and the table fields).

Any idea/tutorial to do that?

Comment: this shows the mapping : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18418/Transferring-Data-Using-SqlBulkCopy

Comment: Any reasons to not use OLEDB Adapter?

Comment: @Sam => Thanks, I'll check that now.

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad => To be honest I'm following the instructions I received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello friend please review this article, i think it will contains all the required information you needed. but you need to do some modification as per your requirement.

[SQLBulk insert from Excel](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/09/import-data-from-excel-to-sql-database.html)

if you are facing any connection issue with your Excel workbook, please modified your excel connection string for that there is a good article provide all the necessary information regarding Excel connection string
[Excel Connection String Sample](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/)